# how to get a value by key from an json (or xml) string?

Tags: java, android, mobile

In the android app I get an xml or json string returned, However, I cant seem to figure out any way on how to get an value from the string in any way by entering an key.

In PHP you just use something like $myArray['parent']['child'] but I have no clue on how this works in java.

Any idea's would be greatly appreciated! (an example for both XML and JSON even more ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public class parsingjsontest2 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(main);

String str = connect("http://rentopoly.com/ajax.php?query=Bo"));
System.out.println("String::"+str);
}
```

}

private String connect(String url)
{

```
// Create the httpclient
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // Prepare a request object
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url); 

    // Execute the request
    HttpResponse response;

    // return string
    String returnString = null;

    try {

       // Open the webpage.
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
            // Connection was established. Get the content. 

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
            // to worry about connection release

            if (entity != null) {
                // A Simple JSON Response Read
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                // Load the requested page converted to a string into a JSONObject.
                JSONObject myAwway = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));

                // Get the query value'
                String query = myAwway.getString("query");

                **// Make array of the suggestions
                JSONArray suggestions = myAwway.getJSONArray("suggestions");

                // Build the return string.
                returnString = "Found: " + suggestions.length() + " locations for " + query;
                for (int i = 0; i < suggestions.length(); i++) {
                    returnString += "\n\t" + suggestions.getString(i);
                }

                // Cose the stream.
                instream.close();
            }
        }
        else {
            // code here for a response othet than 200.  A response 200 means the webpage was ok
            // Other codes include 404 - not found, 301 - redirect etc...
            // Display the response line.
            returnString = "Unable to load page - " + response.getStatusLine();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException  ex) {
        // thrown by line 80 - getContent();
        // Connection was not established
        returnString = "Connection failed; " + ex.getMessage();
    }
    catch (JSONException ex){
        // JSON errors
        returnString = "JSON failed; " + ex.getMessage();
    }
    return returnString;
}

private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
     * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
     * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
     * and returned as String.
     */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Im going to have a look at this when I get home, Thanks! will mark it as an answer if it works for me.

Comment: Well the code itself didnt do what I needed it to do, but i managed to do something with it which does do what I needed it to do, so im going to mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would do:

1. locate an XML/JSON library (there's tons) ([google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for json)
2. read the documentation to find a `parse` method (`(new JsonParser()).parse(text)`)
3. read the documentation to find out what the return value is (`JsonElement`)
4. decide what you want to do with the parsed data (`myJsonObj.get(...)`)
5. write the code

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't specify what kind of xml you are trying to read, I'm answering based on what I know.

In Android, if you were talking about the layout and strings.xml files, you use a dot (.) operator, like R.string.appname.

Please post more details about your specific problem, if this is not what you were looking for.